# Is it possible to boot a 64 bit ISO image with a 32 bit Grub2?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to make a USB stick with multiple OSs installed however wanted it to run on most computers so I made sure to install a 32 bit Ubuntu version. I also want to put a specific ISO on the end and add it as a boot option but the distro only comes as 64 bit. I tried to start up the USB on a 64 bit computer (but 32 bit Grub2 from the Ubuntu install) and tried to boot the ISO (after messing with the grub config) and I ended up getting a kernal freak instantly. I was wondering if it could be because a 32 bit boot loader was trying to start a 64 bit OS or if it's even possible.

Comment: @MarkKirby Alright, so it is probably a problem with the image and grub should just be able to attempt to boot any image, no matter the architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible. I have done it many times.

If you install the 64-bit version after the 32-bit version, and you want to be sure that the original grub (installed with the 32-bit version) is used for booting (in BIOS mode), you should select 'Something else' at the partitioning window of the installer and at the bottom of the window install the bootloader to the partition, 'PBR', (for example to what is going to be the root partition, which might be `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda6`) and not to the head of the drive, 'MBR'.

When you reboot after this procedure, you will only find the 32-bit operating system. Run the following command,

```
sudo update-grub
```

to make it search for and find the new 64-bit version and create menu entries for the grub menu, so that you can select either of the 32-bit and 64-bit version.

After updating & dist-upgrading the 64-bit system with a new kernel you must repeat the command `sudo update-grub` in the 32-bit system to get menu entries for the new kernel version.

---

I checked the grub bootloader of 64-bit Ubuntu, and it is not 64-bit, it works in a 32-bit computer (my old Dell Dimension 4600 with Pentium 4) even without this precaution. (The general recommendation is to install the bootloader to the head of a drive, `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` ... , there should be no partition number.)

If you go this way, after updating & dist-upgrading the 32-bit system with a new kernel you must run the command `sudo update-grub` in the 64-bit system to get menu entries for the new kernel version.

---

If you want to boot from an iso file via grub, you can add a menuentry via `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and after that run `sudo update-grub` according to the following link and links from it,

[Installation/FromUSBStick - Booting USB drives with grub2 and iso files 'grub-n-iso'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_USB_drives_with_grub2_and_iso_files_.27grub-n-iso.27)

Comment: Thank you. I guess it was just something wrong with the ISO file I was trying to start or how I was starting it.

Comment: Good luck :-) Please let us know the result, whatever it is. If you have problems, I will try to help you.  It is getting late here, so I will soon go to sleep. But I will check for comments/questions from you tomorrow.